How to get string "arm64" on an aarch64 Linux system?
I want to get the string arm64 in a bash script.
root@ubuntu-arm-test:# uname -a

Linux ubuntu-arm-test 5.15.0-105-generic #115-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 09:52:04 UTC 2024 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

I could do something like this:
#!/bin/bash

# Get the machine hardware name
arch=$(uname -m)

# Convert aarch64 to arm64
if [ "$arch" == "aarch64" ]; then
    echo "arm64"
else
    echo "$arch"
fi

But I would like to have a simpler way.
root@ubuntu-arm-test:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/arch
cat: /proc/sys/kernel/arch: No such file or directory

root@ubuntu-arm-test:~# uname -a
Linux ubuntu-arm-test 5.15.0-105-generic #115-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 09:52:04 UTC 2024 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

Update
I am very confused. The string arm64 is very common in package names, and there is no straight forward way to get to this string.

What it says in cat /proc/sys/kernel/arch?

@LéaGris I updated the question and added the output. /proc/sys/kernel/arch does not exist on my arm64 Ubuntu 22.04 system.

Of course, you could also just shorten your if/else statement: [[ "$arch" == "aarch64" ]] && echo "arm64" || echo "$arch". Then it would become a one-liner without the need of using if and else, but I'd strongly recommend the answer given by @nomad85

You can do this in one line using sed:
arch=$(uname -m | sed 's/^aarch64$/arm64/')


You could use bash variable substitution as well:
arch=$(uname -m)
echo ${arch/aarch64/arm64}


On Debian systems you can use:
dpkg --print-architecture


If you have Go installed:
go env GOARCH


arm64

